# How to display the custom user profile property in the Details section on the editprofile.aspx page

Tags: my-site, my-profile, user-profile, configuration

Environment:
**SharePoint 2010**

Part-A:

Is it possible change the user profile property order across the sections?

Let's say
 1. We have a custom property group called "custom group"
 2. It has the property "XYZ"
 3. Is it possible place the property "XYZ" in the middle of the "Details" section?

Part-B:

I have created a new custom user profile property called "XYZ" and wants to display this under the Details section instead of under its own section name ("Custom Property") is on the editprofile.aspx page.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Part-C:

How to create a new property under the "Details" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Manage User Properties" of the page, there are arrows to move a property up and down and even change the sections. I quickly tested it and it works!

Comment: Do you mean to say that you were able to move the property from a section to another?

Comment: Is there a way to add a user profile property under the details section?

Comment: Yes, I was able to move it from custom group to details group using those arrows. I was not able to add it directly to details section though.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010, there is a tool helping to move those properties http://mossprofileordering.codeplex.com/

In SharePoint 2013 it can be done with powershell, since ordering via UI always gets stuck with "Picture Placeholder State" property

```
$MySite = Get-SPSite [MySiteHostURL]
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $MySite
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
#check current order numbers
$profilemanager.properties | ft name,displayorder

# set an order number for property, which does not yet exist
$profileManager.Properties.SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName(“CustomProperty”,30)
$profileManager.Properties.CommitDisplayOrder()
```

http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2014/02/moving-user-properties-up-in-sharepoint-with-powershell/